# Nancy Self-Host 404 Errors

Tags: nancy, self-hosting

I'm trying to build a simple Nancy self host. I got it working if I send in the proper path, but if I send empty path after port #, I get is error 404. If I send an invalid path I get error 500. What I want is to have a catch-all Get which is used whenever a request is sent with an invalid path.

Here is my program.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Hosting.Self;

namespace NancyDataService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
            var hostConfig = new HostConfiguration();
            hostConfig.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;
            hostConfig.RewriteLocalhost = false;
            using (var nancyHost = new NancyHost(uri, new DefaultNancyBootstrapper(), hostConfig))
            {
                nancyHost.Start();

                Console.WriteLine("Nancy now listening on http://localhost:8080. Press enter to stop");
                try
                {
                    Process.Start("http://localhost:8080");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopped. Good bye!");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main module:

```
using Nancy;

namespace NancyDataService
{
    public class MainModule: NancyModule
    {
        public MainModule()
        {
            string json_error = @"{""status"":""fail"",""reason"":""{0}""}";
            string json;

            Get("test", parms =>
            {
                return "test";
            });

            // this is default if desired path not sent
            Get("{parm1}", parms =>
            {
                json = string.Format(json_error, "Invalid method name supplied");
                //return (Response)json;
                return json;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the Get syntax to match the Nancy 2.0 way. I was expecting that the last Get in the above code would be processed, and give me a default error message. If I enter `http://localhost:8080/` in browser, I get error 404 response. If I enter `http://localhost:8080/test` it works fine. If I enter `http://localhost:8080/anythingElse` I get Error 500, Internal Server Error.

What I would like is to have a "default" get section so any unexpected path entered (including no path at all) after port #, it would take that branch.

BTW, this is targeting .Net Core 3.0, which Nancy says may not work. The warning in my Nancy.Hosting.Self package has a warning which says it was restored using .Net Framework (4.6.1 - 4.8). Could that be the issue?

Any ideas how to make that work? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Solved most issues. Need `Get("/", ...` for empty path, and `Get("/{parm}",...` for bad path. Seems `string.Format` causes error 500 but `json_error.Replace("{0}", "new text")` works fine. What's up with that?